# Why does maya randomly turn my image plane into a blank rectangle?

Tags: 3d-modeling, maya

I am learning Maya. I could use some help understanding why this keeps happening.
The image plane goes from THIS:

[image]

to THIS:

[image]

Randomly. Then I have to reopen my scene to get the image to show up but in about a minute it goes back to being blank.

Am not doing anything fancy, Just animating a camera facing down, along a motion path. The image is quite large, here some information about it:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| File Size | 881 MiB |
| File Type | BTF |
| File Extension | tif |
| Bits Per Sample | 8 8 8 8 |
| Image Size | 31553x16237 |
| Megapixels | 512.3 |

And my PCs specs are:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | AMD Ryzen 9 5950X |
| Ram | 128 GB |
| GPU | RTX 3090 |

I really don't want use to a low resolution image, as the whole point of my project is demonstrate the high imaging capabilities of the drone that captured the image.

I figured I would just suffer it to the end of my project by reloading the scene, but I really want to learn Maya inside out. I would appreciate any insight into what could be the cause, thank you.

Comment: What are your computer's hardware specs?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Maya, but the standard approach in video editors is to use *proxy media* rather than trying to do live previews at 8k, dragging your system to its knees. So for construction you use cheap/fast media which at final render automatically uses the original high-def.

Comment: https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-E9B50850-39EF-4BFC-97EB-08F008847CCA